# What is the default Critical Strike chance?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are lots of ways to increase the chance of a [Critical Strike](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Critical_strike#Increasing_critical_strike_chance), but how do I know what the default is?  Is it the same for all characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Default critical strike chance of all champions and non-wolf mobs is 0%.

This wasn't true back during the beta, but in present day LoL, it is impossible to get critical strike chance without runes or items.

Notable perceived exceptions are Ashe and Tryndamere, who get crit from their passive abilities, but these buffs adjust upwards from the same base of 0%.

Comment: Yep, it used to be 4% with the talents which they now nerfed to some crappy +0.5 damage per level as 4 points...

Comment: @Lyrion the scaling AD/level is actually a slightly better deal, in terms of gold equivalency.

Comment: Only slightly + counting that you get to lvl 18 wich adds to +9 bonus damage, but i would still have preffered the 4% random crit at lvl 1-18 over 9 extra damage at lvl 18. +0.5 for 4 points investement isn't really that much.

Comment: @Lyrion The 4% crit chance was removed for the same reason base critical % was removed. That said - this conversation isn't suitable for comments. I'd be more than happy to talk this over with you in chat, however.