# Can damage from thornmail critically strike?

Tags: league-of-legends

After playing a game as Nautilus, I was surprised to see that I had critically striked.  I do have a rune page that gives a chance to critically strike, but I'm sure I didn't select it.

Do critical strikes vs thornmail count for the owner?

[image: Proof of the critical strike]
[image: Nautlius Items]

Comment: @Ktash I get this too sometimes as many other heroes, I've noticed it from time to time. You crit in a game when you had no reason to ever do so, no crit from any stat ever, yet you crit, how?

Comment: Hi Toast. I think as your question stands, it is a bit too localized. Might want to broaden your question to be more general.

Comment: I'm trying to ascertain whether a bug exists in the game, or whether it's a lack of understanding on my part.  Though it is very specific, it's directly about game mechanics.  Could you elaborate on why you think it's too localized?

Comment: I'd suggest you rename this to, 'Can Thornmail damage crit?', as otherwise you're asking us to prove a negative.

Comment: Just an observation - Malz had 204 crit damage as well, without any AD items.  I'm guessing no crit runes on him either.  I don't think it is related to the thornmail

Comment: Also - see this page: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49554/what-is-the-default-critical-strike-chance

Comment: Good catch @BrianH.  It seems unlikely that Riot would put critical chance runes on Malzahar.

Comment: @Toast, not sure about riot, but I always put 1 crit rune in all of my rune pages, just for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug where you have like a .00001% chance of getting a critical hit even without any critical strike items. Minions do it occasionally.

As for thornmail, it deals magic damage as a percentage of the net total damage you receive. So I believe the fact that the dmg is magic answers your question. We can't talk about critical magic dmg (that would be...interesting lol)

Comment: Do you have any references for this bug?

Comment: Unfortunately no reliable references. Just personal experience and some discussions in the NA lol forums. I looked into it a while ago cause I had the same question...

Answer (score 1):

Thornmail itself does not do a set amount of damage, it is based on the enemy... If an enemy crits you, they will take more damage than if a normal autoattack hits you.